# Can $DateTime.Now.Year be used with NVelocity to display the current year?

Tags: templates, velocity, nvelocity

Sorry that this is kind of a lazy questions...

I'm curious if $DateTime.Now.Year can be used with NVelocity templates to show the current year?  Or do I need to set a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I know NVelocity templates only work with objects set in the VelocityContext.

Answer (score 0):

But there is no problem with adding your custom objects to the context and then use them in the template.

```
_context = new VelocityContext();
_context.Put("your_key", your_object);
```